# Two primefaces contextMenu in a same form

Tags: forms, primefaces, contextmenu

I need to put a contextMenu in a datatable and to put another contextMenu around the datatable.

I dont know how to works contextMenu together in a same form

```
<p:contextMenu for="grid">
                <p:menuitem value="Baixar" update="teste" icon="ui-icon-disk" actionListener="#{acervoBean.downloadNovo()}" ajax="false">
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{acervoBean.fileDownload}"/>
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Excluir" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Renomear" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Transferir" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-extlink"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Copiar" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Versões anteriores" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
            </p:contextMenu>

            <p:contextMenu for="form">
                <p:menuitem value="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Update" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Homepage" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-extlink"/>
            </p:contextMenu>
```

My dataTable

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{acervoBean.listaArquivoDigital}" var="obj" id="grid"
                             paginator="false" 
                             selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{acervoBean.arquivoDigitalSelected}" rowKey="#{obj.id}"
                             emptyMessage="Nenhum registro foi localizado.">

                    <p:column headerText="ID" width="30">
                        <h:outputText value="#{obj.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
```

Someone help me?

Comment: You cannot ask for help without showing your research.

Comment: Thank I put part of my code